# Does the sentence "Because we won't ever want to get enough sleep" make sense?

Tags: meaning

At about 0:31 into a [video](https://youtu.be/PTdVzr7C3g8?t=26) (the link starts at 0:26), the speaker says

> Project one has already been released. It was originally due Friday but we decided to push back and give everyone a little more time till Sunday.
>
> Because we won't ever want to get enough sleep this week's gonna be really hectic as it is getting set up with everything.

I know the basic idea is that the instructor's team decided to postpone the deadline to give students more time.

The word "as" between "this week's gonna be really hectic" and "it is getting set up with everything" indicates "it is getting set up with everything" is one of the reasons that "this week's gonna be really hectic".

I'm confused about the part "Because we won't ever want to get enough sleep."

I guess the speaker was actually trying to say something like "we'll be extremely busy this week, due Friday would make it much busier, so due Sunday."

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writer is employing **irony** - saying the opposite of what he or she means, as a form of humorous emphasis. The schedule is being extended "because we won't ever want to get enough sleep (*because we **always** want to get enough sleep)*".

> irony    noun    [U] (TYPE OF SPEECH)   C2
>
> the use of words that are the opposite of what you mean, as a way of
> being funny:
>
> *Her voice heavy with irony, Simone said, "We're so pleased you were able to stay so long." (= Her voice made it obvious they were not
> pleased.)*